# Retrofit 2: отправка файла

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Необходимо отправить фото, header и несколько полей в form-data.

Если отдельно отправить фото, то оно отправляется на сервер успешно.(status 200)

Если отправить фото вместе с полями form-data, то фото не приходит на сервер, а поля приходят.(status 200).

**Помогите, может в коде что-то не так написал**

**Запрос в Postman работает правильно:**
[image: 1]

**Код интерфейса:**

```
@Multipart
@PATCH("user")
Call<UserData> updateUserData(@Header("ACCESS-TOKEN") String accessToken
                            , @QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap
                            , @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

**Код вызова метода:**

```
public static void udpateUserDataWithPhoto(Callback<UserData> callback, Map<String, String> map1) {
        String token = SharedPreferenceStorage.getInstance().getServerAccessToken();    
        File file = new File(Constants.PATH_TO_PROFILE_PHOTO + "avatar.jpg");
        MultipartBody.Part body = prepareFilePart(USER_profile_photo, file);

        App.getApi().updateUserData(token, map1, body).enqueue(callback);

    }

    private static MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, File file) {

        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
        if (mimeType != null) {

            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file);
            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Код создания объекта Retrofit2:**

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)) //logging
                .build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL) //Базовая часть адреса
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Конвертер, необходимый для преобразования JSON'а в объекты
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        iRetrofit = retrofit.create(IRetrofit.class); //Создаем объект, при помощи которого будем выполнять запросы

// ...

public static IRetrofit getApi() {
    return iRetrofit;
}
```

**Логи:**
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Самое странное, что при отправке 3 полей и файла - сервер отдаёт статус 200 и принимает строки, но не принимает файл.

В постмэне этот запрос проходит без проблем (1я картинка)

Если отправлять только файл, без 3 этих полей - сервер так же отдаёт статус 200 и принимает этот файл-картинку нормально. (в логах видно)

**Может ли быть, что поля конфликтуют с Multipart?**

**Используемые версии библиотек**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из этих статей

[how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server)

[passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap)

понял, что там QueryMap не подходит.

Изменил методы так:

```
@NonNull
public static RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    return RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
}

public static void udpateUserDataWithPhoto(Callback<UserData> callback, HashMap<String, RequestBody> map) {
// метод меняет только входной параметр на HashMap<String, RequestBody>
}

заполнение массива в метод выше такое:

RequestBody pName = RetrofitQueries.createPartFromString("" + userData.getFirstName());
    RequestBody pLastname = RetrofitQueries.createPartFromString("" + userData.getLastName());
    RequestBody pUsername = RetrofitQueries.createPartFromString("" + userData.getUsername());

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(RetrofitQueries.USER_first_name, pName);
    map.put(RetrofitQueries.USER_last_name, pLastname);
    map.put(RetrofitQueries.USER_username, pUsername);
```

Метод интерфейса стал таким:

```
@Multipart
@PATCH("user")
Call<UserData> updateUserData(@Header("ACCESS-TOKEN") String accessToken
                            , @PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> partMap
                            , @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Дело было в том, что при отправке Multipart файла, необходимо отправлять строки form-data также через @Part / @PartMap